# How to use whereBetween in whereRelation Laravel 8

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-8

I want to use something like whereBetween or another to filter created_at in 'accountLog' model using whereRelation

```
Account::with('accountLog')->get();
```

how can i do that?

Answer (score 3):

I think its not available yet if you want to use whereBetween capabilities using whereRelation

Hence, you can achieve same way like this

```
Account::with('accountLog', function($query) use ($start, $end) {
    $query->whereBetween('created_at', [$start, $end]);
})->get();
```

Comment: This Will Work .. I think ?

Comment: yup its working in this way. Very common approach

Comment: i want to try this code, but i have error like this 'syntax error, unexpected token "}"',
i belive its error beacuse i use php 8 
https://3v4l.org/M3Xud

can you help me?

Comment: must be syntax error somewhere. Is your IDE not showing error?

Answer (score 0):

whereBetween is just like where and you can use it the same way :

```
Account::with('accountLog')->whereBetween('created_at', [$startDate, $endDate])
```

You should check the doc : https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/queries#additional-where-clauses

Comment: sorry if my question is not clear, but i want filter created_at column in accountLog
not in Account, i have tried your answer but its not work
thanks

Comment: Read question carefully.  Johan wants to search in the relation ‘accountLog’. Your answer will not helpful because you are apply whereBetween in Account.